# post to wcf using volley (android)

Tags: android-volley

i am trying to solve this error from a week but any of my workaround is not working unfortunately

i am trying to send json String like this String={"name":"ABC"} to WCF(ASP.NET) using volley library post method but its not working anyhow gives this error

BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://192.168.1.11/MyDemoService/Service1.svc/insert

i am not sure what is wrong and where is the mistake is being made

**Here is the WCF Code:**

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "insert", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        string insert(string name);
```

**insert Function :**

```
public string insert(string name)
        {
            //write database related insert logic here.
           //string response2="{\"name\":\"mohib\"}";




            //info m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<info>(name);
            //string n = m.name;



           // string ds = name;



            string conStr = @"Data Source=CRESIDIAN-DELL;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;User Id=sa;Password=1234";
         //   string msg = "true";
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

                con.Open();
                string query = "insert into DemoTable (name) values ('" + name + "')";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                msg = "Inserted";
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 e.ToString();
            }

            return msg;










        }
```

**WCF Web Config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services >
      <service name="WCFDemo.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFDemo.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="MyConfig">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors >
        <behavior name="MyConfig">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Volley Code in Android (Client):**

```
     String url="http://192.168.1.11/MyDemoService/Service1.svc/insert";

     JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    params.put("name", "true");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        url, params,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                //Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                Log.d("Tag",response.toString());
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {

                    /**
                     * Passing some request headers
                     * */
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        return headers;
                    }

                };
                jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

// Adding request to request queue
                BaseApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,"Post Request");
```